# Conditionally pause Javascript to wait for ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

The variable ajaxdata is modified within the success function, if that hasn't been done yet, I would like to wait 2 seconds, then continue without it.

The use case is for a jqueryui autocomplete field.  The autocomplete source is an ajax request, but if the user types quickly, and exits the field before the list loads, the field remains unset.  Using the 'change' event on the autocomplete I check if the user entered a valid option without selecting it, but this doesn't work if the source hasn't loaded when the change event fires.  So I would like to put a delay in the change function which waits, if the source (stored in the variable 'ajaxdata') is empty.

code:

```
input.autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response){
                    $.ajax(
                        {
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/some/url",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function(data){
                                response($.map(data,function(item){
                                    return{
                                        label: item.label,
                                        value: item.value
                                    }
                                }));
                                ajaxdata = data;
                            }
                        }
                    );
                    // ajaxopts = ajaxsource(request,response,ajaxurl,xtraqry)
                },                   
            change: function(event, ui) {
                if (!ui.item) {
                    // user didn't select an option, but what they typed may still match
                    var enteredString = $(this).val();
                    var stringMatch = false;
                    if (ajaxdata.length==0){
                        ///  THIS IS WHERE I NEED A 2 SECOND DELAY
                    }
                    var opts = ajaxdata;
                    for (var i=0; i < opts.length; i++){
                        if(opts[i].label.toLowerCase() == enteredString.toLowerCase()){
                            $(this).val(opts[i].label);// corrects any incorrect case
                            stringMatch = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }
            },
        });
```

Edit:

To be more specific about the problem:  This delay needs to be conditional.  Meaning that if the data is already loaded (either because it came from a static source, or from an earlier ajax call) I do not want to have a delay.

Comment: You DO NOT need a two second delay (which can easily be achieved with setTimeout by the way), you need to wait until the ajax call is FINISHED!

Comment: Have you tried using the `beforeSend:` or `complete:` settings of the `$.ajax()`? You can bind functions to execute before the HTTP Request is sent and when it's been completed.

Comment: See this can help you what you want to achieve. http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing1

Comment: You have gone out of your way to describe the usage case but it's unclear. At least, I can't follow it.

Comment: My initial design did not wait for ajax to finish, because it relied on some other code if the ajax request took too long.  That could potentially be changed.  It seems that setTimeout should be easy to implement but I was having a difficult time getting it work as I thought it should, an example would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you properly, I think you just want to check and see if `ajaxdata` has been populated; but if it hasn't, only wait two more seconds and then just proceed without it.

Try this:

```
change: function(event, ui) {
    if (!ui.item) {
        // user didn't select an option, but what they typed may still match

        if (ajaxdata.length==0){
            ///  THIS IS WHERE I NEED A 2 SECOND DELAY

            //pass in 'this' so that you can use it
            setTimeout(function() {correctCase(this);}, 2000);
        }       
    }
}
```

. . . . .

```
function correctCase(inThis){       

    //I'm not sure what this variable does.  do you really need it???   
    var stringMatch = false;

    var enteredString = $(inThis).val();
    //you still want to be sure that ajaxdata is not empty here
    if (ajaxdata.length==0){
        var opts = ajaxdata;
        for (var i=0; i < opts.length; i++){
            if(opts[i].label.toLowerCase() == enteredString.toLowerCase()){
                $(inThis).val(opts[i].label);   // corrects any incorrect case
                stringMatch = true;  //this variable doesn't seem to do anything after this???
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what it is you're trying to do, but I'm pretty sure something like this would be a better way of doing it :

```
input.autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/some/url",
            dataType: "json"
        });
    },
    change: function(event, ui) {
        if (!ui.item) {
            // user didn't select an option, but what they typed may still match
            var enteredString = this.value;
            var stringMatch = false;
            //make sure ajax is complete
            this.source().done(function(data) {
                var opts = $.map(data, function(item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.label,
                        value: item.value
                    }
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < opts.length; i++) {
                    if (opts[i].label.toLowerCase() == enteredString.toLowerCase()) {
                        $(this).val(opts[i].label); // corrects any incorrect case
                        stringMatch = true;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Currently this is part of some fairly generic code, which can use either a static or ajax data source.  In the case that is is static, "this.source().done()" will not be available.  Do you have any suggestions to accommodation that?

Answer (score 0):

By default, JavaScript is asynchronous whenever it encounters an async function, it queued that function for later.
But if you want a pause js(ajax call or anything) for you can do it use promises
Case 1: output hello(will not wait for setTimeout)
https://jsfiddle.net/shashankgpt270/h0vr53qy/

```
//async 
function myFunction() {
let result1='hello'
//promise =new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
setTimeout(function(){ 
resolve("done");
result1="done1";
}, 3000);
//});
 //result = await promise
 alert(result1);
}
myFunction();
```

case 2: output done1(will wait for setTimeout)
https://jsfiddle.net/shashankgpt270/1o79fudt/

```
async function myFunction() {
let result1='hello'
promise =new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
setTimeout(function(){ 
resolve("done");
result1="done1";
}, 3000);
});
 result = await promise
 alert(result1);
}
myFunction();
```